# How to use bootsrap navbar and browser router together

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am new user of react i am trying to link pages but with bootstrap navigation but its not working.
I am tring to use the react router dom to make different pages so that it can go to different pages on click but the app does not compile since browser router is not being imported. I just copy pasted it straight from the website. Can someone tell me where the mistake is and how to fix it
It shows nothing on browser but a blank page[![enter image description here]  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf4Sz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf4Sz.png) here is the picture that shows some errors in console but not on browser

app,js

```
import Home from './Components/Home'
       - import Contact from './Components/Contact'
       - import About from './Components/About'
       - import { BrowserRouter,
       - Routes,Route } from 'react-router-dom'
       -   <BrowserRouter>
       -       <Routes>
       -           <Route  path="/" element={<Home />}>
       -           <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
       -           <Route path="/ContactUs" element={<Contact />} />
       -         </Route>
       -       </Routes>
       -     </BrowserRouter>
       - 
       - navbar.js
       -   <Navbar expand="lg" >
       -         <Container>
       -         <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
       -         <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
       -           <Nav className="me-auto">
       -             <LinkContainer to='/'>
       -             <Nav.Link >HOME</Nav.Link></LinkContainer>
       -             <LinkContainer><Nav.Link to="/About">ABOUT</Nav.Link></LinkContainer>
       -             <LinkContainer><Nav.Link to="/services">SERVICES</Nav.Link></LinkContainer>
       -             <LinkContainer> <Nav.Link to="/">WRITE</Nav.Link></LinkContainer>
       - 
               
       -           </Nav>
       -           </Navbar.Collapse>
       -         </Container>
       -       </Navbar>`
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to nest your Navbar inside the BrowseerRouter tag.
Example:

```
    <Header/>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <NavigationBar />
            <Routes>
                <Route path={"/"}></Route>
                <Route path={"/example"}></Route>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I did this but same problem